# Eloquent is generating bad update query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to **update** a record just after I get it from database.

```
$item = Model::find($id);
$item->field = 'foo';
$item->save();
```

it do **finds** the requested record, but the query generated to update the record is **not** correct:

```
update `Models` set `field` = ? where `id` is null
```

I don't know why this is happening!

what is wrong ?

**Update:**

I just renamed the `primary-Key` from `ID` to `id` in the database table. and then it worked! I didn't know it's case-sensitive

```
update `bannerads_orders` set `ViewedCount` = ? where `id` = ?
```

Comment: have you defined a new model called "Model", or is that just an example ?

Comment: @msturdy, no it's an example. updated the answer

Comment: What is returned if the supplied '$id' does not exist. I assume an 'empty' 'Model' object with an id of 'null'. I would not expect the ORM to try an update a record that is 'new'. I would expect an 'insert' to happen.

Comment: @JaredEitnier: yes, but nothing happens.

Comment: And you've checked the raw database table and have verified all the data is correct? That you're calling the correct ID, etc.?

Comment: @RyanVincent : I have checked the returned value.it do returns a matched record.

Comment: The update statement is correct, except it should have  a 'where' clause of: where `id` = $id.

Comment: @RyanVincent :-) , how is that ?!

Comment: var_dump($item), the the returned record. It will have an 'id' that is specific to the record that you selected from the database. Let us say the id is100. Therefore $item->save() will generate  an update statement with a where clause of  `id` = 100. Or a bind value of 100.

Comment: @RyanVincent: correct, and that's what I expected to see.

Comment: @RyanVincent: I updated the answer. the problem was simple but still strange. fixed now. thank you anyway

Comment: It may be useful to add an answer that the 'id' column name and use is 'case-sensitive' in 'Laravel' generated code. It may help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found the problem. as Laravel documents says:

> Note: Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key
>   column named id. You may define a primaryKey property to override this
>   convention

but in my table it was `ID` not `id`. so after I changed it to `id`, everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for posting that the id' field is 'lower case dependent'. was a lot of fun getting here.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). There is nothing wrong with this. Additionally you don't actually specify an error.

Comment: Well, there is no error. the problem is that the query for update is not correct and is not updating the record.

Comment: Thanks for your point. I found the problem and updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use in this case:

```
$item = Model::findOrfail($id);
$item->field = 'foo';
$item->save();
```

It seems that `$id` might be null or user cannot be found and than saving it doesn't make any sense.

If user is not found exception will be thrown and this save won't be executed

Comment: Thanks for your point. I found the problem and updated the question.